# Table tr border width 100%

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I want to make my border-top full table width but it's only taking my table data (td) size...

The last tr have my border-top but it's not taking the full size of the table.

```css
        th {
      border: 0 solid #581D74;
      border-bottom-width: 1px;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    tr, td, th {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 15px;
    }


    .add-btn {
      min-width: 0;
      color: white;
    }

    .add-icon {
      color: #581d74;
    }

    .total-row {
      border: 0 solid #581d74;
      border-top-width: 1px;
      padding: 15px;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
```

```html
<table class="disinves-table">
        <tr class="table-header">
          <th></th>
          <th>head 1</th>
          <th>head 2</th>
          <th>head3</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><button mat-button class="add-btn"><mat-icon class="add-icon">add_circle</mat-icon></button></td>
          <td>first data</td>
          <td>19%</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="total-row">
          <td>Total</td>
          <td></td>
          <td>8654</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are asking
From my understanding of your question:

You would like the table headers to have a border that fills the table width
but its only filling the table row (tr) 

It is doing procesely that given you do not have a class in your css called disinves-table with a width property and therefore it wraps the width of the table around the total collective table cell widths

Comment: .disinves-table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

I actually got it ^^" sorry.

So in my last tr with the total-row class, I want it have a full width (the table width) border top. for now it's just taking the border of my td.

Comment: To be able to style a `tr`, the `table` needs to have `table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
`. Furthermore, you need to either have the same amount of `td` as you have `th`, or use `colspan` on one of the `td` or the `tr` won't fill full table width

Answer (score 1):

If you are complaining about the gaps you see in the border, that is because the default style of a table is to have a few pixels of space between the cells.
Solution: set the table's `border-spacing` to `0`.

```css
.disinves-table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
  border: 0 solid #581D74;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  padding: 15px;
}

tr, td, th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

.add-btn {
  min-width: 0;
  color: white;
}

.add-icon {
  color: #581d74;
}

.total-row {
  border: 0 solid #581d74;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table class="disinves-table">
  <tr class="table-header">
    <th></th>
    <th>head 1</th>
    <th>head 2</th>
    <th>head3</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><button mat-button class="add-btn"><mat-icon class="add-icon">add_circle</mat-icon></button></td>
    <td>first data</td>
    <td>19%</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="total-row">
    <td>Total</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>8654</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Good evening Mr :) ...am sure they look for this: "To be able to style a `tr`, the `table` needs to have `table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
`. Furthermore, you need to either have the same amount of `td` as you have `th`, or use `colspan` on one of the `td` or the `tr` won't fill full table width"

Comment: @LGSon You can post that as an answer yourself. After your explanation, it's wholly possible that that's what the OP meant rather than the gaps. Oh well.

Comment: Good Morning Guys =). So actually yeah I just add some more td in my table et it's working fine ^^. But yeah the advice of the colspan would work fine I think =).
Thanks for you answers guys, I don't know how to put you comment into the answer ^^' so If you can put it =).